# Cannot get angularjs http request message data at node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, xmlhttprequest

The client side code snippet:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/admin?operation=getAdminInfo',
  data: {data: 'test'}
}).then(function(rsp){...});
```

The server side code snippet:

```
console.log('req = ' + req);
console.log('req.header = ' + JSON.stringify(req.header));
console.log('req.query = ' + JSON.stringify(req.query));
console.log('req.body = ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
console.log('req.cookies = ' + JSON.stringify(req.cookies));
console.log('req.params = ' + JSON.stringify(req.params));
console.log('req.xhr = ' + JSON.stringify(req.xhr));
```

The output in the server console:

```
req = [object Object]
req.header = undefined
req.query = {"operation":"getAdminInfo"}
req.body = {}
req.cookies = {"token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzeXN0ZW0iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5uZXRhb3RlYy5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1MTYwNjM1Njk1MDQsInVzZXJfcm9sZSI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJzeXN0ZW0iLCJleHAiOjE1MTYwNjM1NzY3MDR9.K2Rh4WTNtkhP2gxWLnGW7846zMKaW-WKEF2hykJmvn3zNmGyIDprrnswzqqrpmAvNTP8gylnCn3b7K_gRJ-WOif7MnQYiG4mu8fNGW-hCUQeTyqzUgsP9sIXzm_A3pWFlW8eL88Dydugf9JhhDeB18QUJV-i4zT6bCfE3stY1QXJZzNsKd8HRl22n78XCb5XRxdiEnmhqF6sNb9h40jKzcd6Ny0KX6uEe1SE54OYbp_BcR4Lr69C6tcFNgwtiJusFEymnMcbkqSst_GUztiObPeYZIwrfEUMEobUsxvx0v2zUQp9EJDF-MyaGid5kJwyv_ittFFKRChBSllI3luNXA"}
req.params = {}
req.xhr = false
```

How can I extract/get the data `{data: 'test'}` at node.js? AngularJS version is 1.6.6; Node.js version is v8.1.4; app.js at node.js: [enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WGt9XIUzAy3Meyiw6g4K?p=catalogue)

Comment: @Sajeetharan, no, no. you take a look at my output, I cannot get the data at node.js. at angularjs side I'm following the instruction of [angularjs document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) strictly. In the document it shows `data – {string|Object} – Data to be sent as the request message data.`

Comment: which is same! you need to strigify the data if you are sending it as ajson, also use http.post with angularjs

Comment: I changed the config to `data: JSON.stringify({data: 'test'})` and get the same result. Also, at the angularjs document, there is an example using code `data: { test: 'test' }`.

Comment: bro check the duplicate marked question, you need to check the headers as well

Comment: Change the config `method: 'GET'` to `method: 'POST'` get the result in req.body. Thank you. But this is not duplicate with the thread you mentioned -- JSON.stringify does not help here.

Comment: ok if you think so let me post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method from Get to Post, since you are sending an object to the server.

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/admin?operation=getAdminInfo',
  data: {data: 'test'}
}).then(function(rsp){...});
```